# A so-called random variable not being well-defined

Tags: randomized-algorithms, randomness

Consider this algorithm:

```
 RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, r, i)
1 if p == r
2  return A[p]
3 q = RANDOMIZED-PARTITION(A, p, r)
4 k = q - p + 1
5 if i == k // the pivot value is the answer
6  return A[q]
7 elseif i < k
8  return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, p, q - 1, i)
9 else return RANDOMIZED-SELECT(A, q + 1, r, i - k)
```

The book CLRS claims that if we set $T(n)$ to be the running time of the algorithm on an input $A$ of size $n$, then $T$ is a random variable. However, I think it's not since if we define $\Omega$
to be the set of all inputs of all sizes $n$ and set $\mathcal{F}$ as $\mathcal{P}(\Omega)$ and let $T$ to be a function from $\Omega$ to $\mathbb{R}$, if $n = m$ then it doesn't follow that $T(n) = T(m)$ since the algorithm might have different running times on arbitrary inputs of the same size. Also note that the algorithm is randomized. So why does it say that $T$ is a random variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your counterargument but look at it like this:

For given $n$ define $\Omega_n$ to be all inputs of size $n$ and $\mathcal{F_n} = \mathcal{P}(\Omega_n)$.

Let $(T_{n})_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions:

$$T_{n} : \Omega_n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$$

Clearly $\forall t,n. \{\omega \mid T_{n}( \omega) \leq t \} \in \mathcal{F_n}$, which shows that $\forall n. T_{n}$ is a random variable on $\Omega_n$.

Comment: Of course we don't need the $T(n, \omega)$ part. Actually, we need to show for any $A$ it's true that $T_{n}^{-1} (A) \in \mathcal{F}_{n}$ which is obvious but the argument is true.

Comment: @Emad This is the usual definition of a random variable. Please see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Real-valued_random_variables

Comment: I see. They're equivalent

Answer (score 1):

Our input is specific, but the input maybe have different permutations, so we can't claim that $T$ is a function that map set of all  inputs to $\mathbb{R}$. But i think, it's true that we look at $T$ as a function that map a input to a permutation, formally, let $X$ be the input of size $n$, and denote $\mathfrak S_n$ be the group of the permutations of $X$ :
$$ T:X\to \mathfrak S_n. $$
So $T$ is a random variable that map input $X$ of size $n$ to $\mathfrak S_n$.

Comment: Since $T$ must be the running time I think we can't define it that way. However, if we compose this function with another function mapping each element of $S_{n}$ to its running time and consider the sequence of such composed functions, then it's something.